# Can someone clarify something in Fubini's theorem please?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In my notes I have a version of Fubini's theorem which differs from the other forms of it I've seen which seem to all be like the one found on wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions).

Here is the version I have in my notes;

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu),\;(Y,\mathcal{B},\nu)$ be complete $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $f$ a function on $X \times Y$ **whose integral with respect to** $\mu \widehat{\otimes} \nu$ **exists** (completion of the product measure $\mu \otimes \nu$). Then;

$\displaystyle\int_{X\times Y} f(x,y)\; d(\mu \widehat{\otimes} \nu)(x,y) = \displaystyle\int_X \bigg(\displaystyle\int_Y f(x,y)\;d\nu(y)\bigg)d\mu(x)= \displaystyle\int_Y \bigg(\displaystyle\int_X f(x,y)\;d\mu(x)\bigg)d\nu(y)$

The subtle difference here is our function is no longer required to be integrable, all that is needed is for the integral to exist. Can someone explain why switching to the completion of the product measure removes the requirement for our function to be integrable? **Note integral exists means it is well defined but possibly infinite. Integrable means the integral is finite.**

As you can see on the wiki page (counterexamples at the bottom) under their conditions if the integral is infinite the theorem does not hold. But here we seem to have removed that issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard about $f = f_{+} - f_{-}$ ?

Comment: Yep, sure have. Why?

Comment: So if we split the integral on the left up it exists iff both of them do not equal infinity. That does not imply the integral of $|f|$ is $<\infty$

Comment: What is meant by "the integral exists" ?

Comment: I would presume that integral existing and integrable mean the same thing here? Or possibly it may be infinite, but well defined in that either $\int f_+$ or $\int f_-$ are finite.

Comment: The latter is true, they are not the same thing. The condition on wiki though is that f is integrable. Sorry will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Tonelli's Theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem%23Tonelli.27s_theorem). The point is that, for a non-negative function, if either iterated integral is finite, then the function is product integrable and you may envoke Fubini's Theorem to conclude that all integrals are equal. In particular, for a positive function, the iterated integrals, in either order, are always equal to the product integral, no matter if the function is integrable or not!

These statements suffice to cover also the case that either the positive part or the negative part of a function is product integrable, do you see how?

In a sense, it is Tonelli's Theorem which gives Fubini's Theorem its strength, since you commonly employ Tonelli's Theorem to show that the function is product integrable.

Comment: I don't know if this particularly answers my question, I understand Tonelli's theorem and I understand why it is so useful for using Fubini's theorem. What I don't understand is why the condition of our function being integrable can be removed. Now for example at the bottom of the wiki we have a non-integrable function whose integral exists and it is shown that Fubini's theorem simply doesn't hold

Comment: Because if the function is positive and not integrable, all integrals are necessarily infinite (and therefore equal), by Tonelli's Theorem.

Comment: So if we have a function which is not always positive and we know the product integral exists, then we spit it up into $f^+$ and $f^-$ and we know at least one of them is not infinite. We know both are positive and so we can apply Tonelli's to each part. Then we can just subtract the corresponding integrals and get our result for $f$? This makes sense but why on wiki does Fubini's theorem require that $|f|$ is integrable? We could have the case that $f^+$ has infinite integral and $f^-$ has finite, then the integral of $|f|$ is infinite but it still works?

Comment: Because that condition, in my experience at least, is typically not very useful. Sure it 'generalizes' Tonelli-Fubini, but the generalization is basically a triviality, which finds little application.

Comment: But at the bottom of the wiki page, the last example, there is a function such that the integral of $|f|$ is infinite but Fubini's theorem does not hold?? This means that there must be some reasoning in my last comment which is incorrect but I can't see what? And so I'm still confused

Comment: I will take a look at the example later, but my guess is that neither the positive nor the negative part is product integrable in that example, so the product integral does not exist

Comment: @Tom For the function of the example which you refer to, the product integral of the positive part is plus infinity, whereas the product integral of the negative part is minus infinity. Therefore, the product integral does not exist, even in the weaker sense that you propose.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, think I've got my head around it now.